Remove a duplicate JDK in JDK choice list in IntelliJ IDEA
While choosing the right JDK for the project I imported the same JDK twice which resulted in the same JDK appearing twice in the selection list. This is ugly and can cause confusion in the future. How can I remove the duplicate? There must be a configuration somewhere which controls it.



Menu File -> Project Structure...


Left: Platform Settings -> SDK
Right:

Select the JDK you want to remove.
Click button - to remove.



